# Breaking cumsum() function at some threshold in r

Tags: r, cumsum

For example I have the following code:

```
cumsum(1:100)
```

And I want to break it,if an element i+1 will be greater than `3000`. How can I do that?

So instead of this result:

```
[1]    1    3    6   10   15   21   28   36   45   55   66   78   91  105  120  136  153  171  190  210  231  253  276  300
 [25]  325  351  378  406  435  465  496  528  561  595  630  666  703  741  780  820  861  903  946  990 1035 1081 1128 1176
 [49] 1225 1275 1326 1378 1431 1485 1540 1596 1653 1711 1770 1830 1891 1953 2016 2080 2145 2211 2278 2346 2415 2485 2556 2628
 [73] 2701 2775 2850 2926 3003 3081 3160 3240 3321 3403 3486 3570 3655 3741 3828 3916 4005 4095 4186 4278 4371 4465 4560 4656
 [97] 4753 4851 4950 5050
```

I want get the following result:

```
 [1]    1    3    6   10   15   21   28   36   45   55   66   78   91  105  120  136  153  171  190  210  231  253  276  300
 [25]  325  351  378  406  435  465  496  528  561  595  630  666  703  741  780  820  861  903  946  990 1035 1081 1128 1176
 [49] 1225 1275 1326 1378 1431 1485 1540 1596 1653 1711 1770 1830 1891 1953 2016 2080 2145 2211 2278 2346 2415 2485 2556 2628
 [73] 2701 2775 2850 2926
```

Comment: There isn't something builtin in R that I'm aware of. You could probably easily write something in Rcpp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, writing something simple in Rcpp shouldn't be a big deal even for someone like myself. Here's a very primitive implementation that seem to work (Thanks to @ MatthewLundberg for the improvements suggestions)

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction('NumericVector cumsumCPP(NumericVector x, int y = 0){

    // y = 0 is the default
    // Need to do this in order to avoid modifying the original x
    int n = x.size();
    NumericVector res(n);
    res[0] = x[0];

    for (int i = 1 ; i < n ; i++) {
      res[i] = res[i - 1] + x[i];
      if (res[i] > y && (y != 0)) { 
        // This breaks the loop if condition met
        return res[seq(0, i - 1)];
      }
    }

    // This handles cases when y== 0 OR y != 0 and y > cumsum(res)
    return res;
}')

cumsumCPP(1:100, 3000)
#  [1]    1    3    6   10   15   21   28   36   45   55   66   78   91  105  120  136  153  171  190  210  231  253  276  300
# [25]  325  351  378  406  435  465  496  528  561  595  630  666  703  741  780  820  861  903  946  990 1035 1081 1128 1176
# [49] 1225 1275 1326 1378 1431 1485 1540 1596 1653 1711 1770 1830 1891 1953 2016 2080 2145 2211 2278 2346 2415 2485 2556 2628
# [73] 2701 2775 2850 2926
```

Similarly to base Rs `cumsum`, this works for both integers and floats and doesn't handles `NA`s. The default value for the treshhold was set to `0` - which is not ideal if you want to limit a negative `cumsum`, but I couldn't think of any better value for now (you can decide on one by yourself).

Though it could use some optimization...

```
set.seed(123)
x <- as.numeric(sample(1:1e3, 1e7, replace = TRUE))
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(cumsum(x), cumsumCPP(x))
# Unit: milliseconds
#         expr      min        lq      mean   median        uq       max neval cld
#    cumsum(x) 58.61942  61.46836  72.50915  76.7568  80.97435  99.01264   100  a 
# cumsumCPP(x) 98.44499 100.09979 110.45626 112.1552 119.22958 131.97619   100   b

identical(cumsum(x), cumsumCPP(x))
## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: You can remove the outer "if" by changing the inner test to `if (y && res[i] > y)`

Comment: @DavidArenburg thanks for the comment on my answer (using base R). You were right - I completely mis-tested it. Have deleted so as not to lead anyone else astray!

Comment: @SimonJackson No need to delete your answer. It is totally fine (we are still in the milliseconds world), I just meant that you need to make sure your benchmark is correct. e.g., in certain cases your implementation will be better, in other cases `cumsum` will win- but still a `while` loop will still be probably more memory efficient or such.

Comment: I ran few larger tests and it gets MUCH slower (def beyond ms timing). Rcpp is far better way to go. One thought for yours - would operating on `x` in place rather than creating `res` speed things up? Would be more memory efficient if nothing else.

Comment: @SimonJackson, yes it will , but it will also modify `x` in global environment and we wouldn't want that. Try `cppFunction('NumericVector test(NumericVector x){ NumericVector res = x; for (int i = 1 ; i < x.size() ; i++) {res[i] = res[i - 1] + x[i];}return res;}') ; x <- as.numeric(sample(10, replace = TRUE)) ; test(x) ; test(x)`. A friend of mine showed me [this](https://teuder.gitbooks.io/introduction-to-rcpp/content/en/08_02_caution_vector.html) as a good read on that topic.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `<=` on the `cumsum` output

```
v1[v1 <=3000]
```

---

Or another option is

```
setdiff(pmin(cumsum(1:100), 3000), 3000)
```

where

```
v1 <- cumsum(1:100)
```