# Search for TRUE in a vector containing TRUE / FALSE

Tags: r

```
A<-(FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE)
```

I want an efficient way to find if A has TRUE and stop when TRUE is found.

Comment: You can do  `A[seq_len(which.max(A))]`  or to be more correct `A[seq_len(which(A)[1])]`

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: You can do this pretty efficiently if you'll write an Rcpp implementation. Just a simple while loop will do.

Comment: It would be interesting to know the rough data size you're dealing with. Is this really a bottleneck?

Comment: I think this is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42328945/breaking-cumsum-function-at-some-threshold-in-r/), but as docendo says, the normal R implementation should be efficient enough for most cases.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to know if `A` contains any `TRUE` values, you can use `any()`:

```
> A <- c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)
> any(A)
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `which` to find the elements that are TRUE, select the first, sequence it and subset the 'A'

```
A[seq_len(which(A)[1])]
```

#### data

```
A <- c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

My first reaction was thinking about `sum(A) != 0` but then went for the `microbenchmark` and these are the results:

```
# install.packages("microbenchmark")
require(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark("sum" = {A <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 1e6, TRUE); sum(A) != 0}, "any" = {A <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 1e6, TRUE); any(A)}, "seq_len" = {A <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 1e6, TRUE); A[seq_len(which(A)[1])]}, times = 100L)

Unit: milliseconds
    expr      min       lq      mean   median       uq      max neval
     sum 72.98672 75.10716  86.33333 76.88114 78.57807 216.4087   100
     any 68.59519 72.35810  78.29730 72.50796 72.83563 229.6932   100
 seq_len 80.41055 84.41244 104.30460 87.82726 90.15668 223.8297   100
```

So definitely `any` seems to be the most efficient (other than a Rcpp implementation)