# cumulative sum with two conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

The given data are fictitious, and in reality they are more complicated

```
t <- data.frame(v1=c(265, -268, 123, 58, 560, 56, -260, 40, 530, -895, 20))
```

I want to count a cumulative sum with two limiting values: 0 and 500.
If the cumulative total exceeds 500 then you must keep 500. If the cumulative total becomes negative then you must store 0 .
The results obtained are as follows:

```
     v1 sum.c
1   265   265
2  -268     0
3   123   123
4    58   181
5   560   500
6    56   500
7  -260   240
8    40   280
9   530   500
10 -895     0
11   20    20
```

The formula in excel would be like this:
=if(B1+A2<0; 0; if(B1+A2>500; 500; B1+A2))

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a `dplyr` based solution for this? 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking the idea from @ThomasIsCoding, here is tidyverse approach:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

t %>%
  mutate(sum.c = accumulate(v1, ~ min(max(.x + .y, 0), 500)))

     v1 sum.c
1   265   265
2  -268     0
3   123   123
4    58   181
5   560   500
6    56   500
7  -260   240
8    40   280
9   530   500
10 -895     0
11   20    20
```

Comment: @GrBa. Thanks for accepting the answer. But you should accept the answer of ThomasIsCoding, because the origin is in his answer. Mine is just a minor adaption! Thank you very much!

Comment: I thought for a long time which answer I should mark. But your answer is more complete. I hope ThomasIsCoding will understand my action.

Answer (score 5):

We can use `min` and `max` to set the boundaries and `Reduce` to iterate the vector

```
> v1 <- c(265, -268, 123, 58, 560, 56, -260, 40, 530, -895, 20)

> Reduce(function(x, y) min(max(x + y, 0), 500),v1, accumulate = TRUE)
 [1] 265   0 123 181 500 500 240 280 500   0  20
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `Rcpp` (Base code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42328945/breaking-cumsum-function-at-some-threshold-in-r)):

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction('NumericVector cumsumCPP(NumericVector x){

    // Need to do this in order to avoid modifying the original x
    int n = x.size();
    NumericVector res(n);
    res[0] = x[0];

    for (int i = 1 ; i < n ; i++) {
      res[i] = res[i - 1] + x[i];
      if (res[i] > 500) { 
        res[i] = 500;
      }
      if (res[i] < 0) {
        res[i] = 0;
      }
    }

    return res;
}')

cumsumCPP(t$v1)
[1] 265   0 123 181 500 500 240 280 500   0  20

library(dplyr)
t%>%mutate(cum_s=cumsumCPP(v1))

     v1 cum_s
1   265   265
2  -268     0
3   123   123
4    58   181
5   560   500
6    56   500
7  -260   240
8    40   280
9   530   500
10 -895     0
11   20    20
```

You can also define your own customize cumulative sum in R.